# Ajax result rows - how to paginate?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

How to paginate my ajax result rows in codeigniter . I want to display my ajax result which would be 10-20 rows in batch  of 4 or 5 rows per page . Hwlp me through. It is not Ajax pagination but it is ajax paginating in an ajax call. Thank you

This is my view file :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#getreport").click(function(){
 var fromdate = $('#date1').val();
 var todate = $('#date2').val();
 $("#header").css("visibility", "visible");
 // $("#bodycontent").empty();
 // $("#bodycontent").html('<div id="subcontent"></div>');
 data =
{
"from"  : fromdate,
"to" : todate
} 
$.post('<?=site_url("Report/managecustomers_report"); ?>', data ,function (data) {
$('#datatable').dataTable({
    data : data
    // columns : [
    // { 'data' : 'picture'},
    // { 'data' : 'customername'},
    // { 'data' : 'contactperson'},
    // { 'data' : 'mobilenumber'},
    // { 'data' : 'phone'},
    // { 'data' : 'email'},
    // ]
});
});     
});
});
</script>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table allcp-form theme-warning fs13">
        <thead>
            <tr class="bg-light">
                <th class="">Image</th>
                <th class="">Customer Name</th>
                <th class="">Contact Person</th>
                <th class="">Mobile Number</th>
                <th class="">Phone</th>
                <th class="">Email</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

My controller :

```
public function managecustomers_report()
{

 $query = $this->Reportmodel->customerreport_select($this->input->post('from'),$this->input->post('to'));
 $data = $query['records'];
  $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
 $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
 return $data;
}
```

My model file :

```
public function customerreport_select($date1,$date2)
{
$this->db->where('date >=', $date1);
$this->db->where('date <=', $date2);
$query=$this->db->get('customers');
$row = $query->result();
print_r($row);
return array(
'records' => $row,
'count' => count($row));
}
```

Comment: you should indent your code...

Comment: It is not good practice, but you can create the html in controller itself and then return that html in your ajax request. And then replace the html using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

try using [jquery datatables](https://datatables.net/) plugin. Server side functionality of jquery datatable exactly serves your need. It is easier to search for data and sort the data column wise.

controller:

```
public function managecustomers_report()
{

 $query = $this->Reportmodel->customerreport_select($this->input->post('from'),$this->input->post('to'));
 $data = $query['records'];
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($data);
}
```

model:

```
public function customerreport_select($date1,$date2)
{
    $this->db->where('date >=', $date1);
    $this->db->where('date <=', $date2);
    $query=$this->db->get('customers');
    $row = $query->result();

    return array(
       'records' => $row,
       'count' => count($row));
}
```

here is my example of implementation of server side functionality, refer this it might help you

view:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#inbox').dataTable( {


         "bServerSide": true,
         "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Inbox_redirect/inbox",
         "bProcessing": true,
        "order": [],
         "bSortable" : true,
          "aaSorting": [[2, 'asc']],
         "sServerMethod": "GET",
         "columns" : [ 
            {"data" : "mailId"},
            {"data" : "mailSender"},
            {"data" : "mailSubject"},
            {"data" : "mailContent"},
            {"data" : "mailSendDate"} ],
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "targets": [ 0 ], //first column / numbering column
            "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],

    } );
} );



</script>
```

controller:

```
public function inbox()
     {
         $data = array(
                    'receiverEmail' => $this->session->userdata['user_login']['loginEmail'],
            );
        $response = $this->mail_receive->inbox($data);

     $output = array(
                        "iTotalRecords" =>$this->mail_receive->totalRecords($data),
                        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $this->mail_receive->totalRecords($data),
                         "aaData" => $response,
                );


        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($output);

     }
```

model:

```
public function inbox($data)
     {
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","mailman");

        $receiverEmail = $data['receiverEmail'];

        $lenghtLimit = $_REQUEST['iDisplayLength'];

        $startLimit = $_REQUEST['iDisplayStart'];

        $searchTerm = $_REQUEST['sSearch'];



        $querySender = "SELECT userId FROM users WHERE userEmail= '$receiverEmail'";
        $resSender = mysqli_query($con, $querySender);
        $rowSender = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resSender);
        $columnSender = $rowSender["userId"]; 


        $querySender = "SELECT mailId,mailSender,mailSubject,mailContent, mailSendDate FROM mails 
                        WHERE mailContent LIKE '%$searchTerm%' 
                        AND mailReceiver = '$columnSender' 
                        LIMIT $lenghtLimit OFFSET $startLimit ";

        $resSender = mysqli_query($con, $querySender);
        $rowSender = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resSender);

        $myMail = array();
        $test = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resSender))     
        {
            $senderId = $row['mailSender'];

            $querySenderName = "SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userId= '$senderId'";
            $resSenderName = mysqli_query($con, $querySenderName);
            $rowSenderName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resSenderName);
            $columnSenderName = $rowSenderName["userName"]; 

            $myMail[] = array(
                'mailId' => $row['mailId'],
                'mailSender' => $columnSenderName,
                'mailSubject' => $row['mailSubject'],
                'mailContent' => $row['mailContent'],
                'mailSendDate' => $row['mailSendDate']
                );

            $test[] = $row;



        }
        $startLimit = $startLimit + $lenghtLimit;
        return $myMail;

    }
```

Comment: I am getting the response data but i am not able to display it !could you check my edited code and help me through

Comment: your controller have some error....I have updated the answer with controller code, try this and let me know

Comment: its not happening :(

Comment: what exactly is the problem? What's the error message? Invalid json response etc.....